# Signal "joiner" for guitar and other electric instruments?

Tags: music

Think of an A/B box. Do those exist in reverse? Say I have an expensive looper and don't want another, or maybe I have a talk-box that I want controlled by both a keyboard and a guitar without having to also switch what my mic is plugged into. Does there exist a pedal or something that has two inputs and one output, where the two inputs don't affect each other? I would be satisfied by something that doesn't even mix the levels of the two instruments, but other people may want that, so include that if there is one.

Comment: Many A/B boxes work in reverse, does that not work for you? Also, if you wanted both instruments to come through at the same time that would be called a mixer.

Comment: I don't have an A/B box so I wouldn't know.

Comment: Well an A/B box is just a switch between two circuits, so it works in either direction. (2 IN / 1 OUT or 1 IN / 2 OUT)

Comment: That's awesome! Should I delete the post? Or maybe you can post that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just need an A/B box.
Most A/B boxes are just a simple switch between the two jacks.

You can use them for two inputs, one output.
Or one input, two outputs.